# Why Magento keeps an old version of Prototype.js?

Tags: magento, prototypejs

In the last 1.9.0.1 Magento Version, it appears that the prototype.js used is the 1.7 from 2010

- Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.7
- (c) 2005-2010 Sam Stephenson

Why they do not use the 1.7.2 released in 2014

Personally I updated the prototype on my website, and it seems that everything works fine, even better.

Do you think the last prototype may have some incompatibility with some Magento stuffs?

Comment: Upgrading from 1.6 caused issues. 1.7.2 is only an incremental upgrade, so it may not. Discussion of why eCommerce developers do what they do isn't really part of this venue, as they do what they darn well please and we deal with the consequences. Programming around the consequences now is a more apt thing to discuss.

Comment: It's not just a simple Why question, I discover recently an upgrade of the google map that is not compatible anymore with the Magento. And the issue is resolved with upgrgading the prototype. The controls on a google map was not showing anymore suddenly after the end of august.

Comment: See, it's always those little additional bits of information that are important to the original question explanation. Should have mentioned why you felt that you needed to upgrade prototype in the question.

Comment: Agreed.  OP could legitimately start a new question with just that bit, then answer it with his own solution.

Comment: finally no need the last prototype.js 1.7.2 to make it work, just mention you are working with the version V3 and it works, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3

Comment: Wow thanks - lifesaver. Setting it to version 3 made it work. @user1423751

Answer (score 5):

You're forgetting the engineers' ethos, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".  Until there is something which can only be fixed by upgrading then there is no point.  Upgrading means extra testing for the rest of the entire application and for enterprise software testing must be very thorough.

Comment: As opposed to the Army Field Engineer rule "If it ain't broke, force it, if it breaks, it needed fixing anyway." Which is a rule that a lot of inexperienced Magento e-commerce website operators run by. I've seen some of the hairiest and weirdest things done to "fix duplicate content" which were already addressed by using canonical tags... And then the website breaks...

Comment: lol, I think you just described fuzz testing.

Comment: Yep! Fuzz testing is cool, except when you do it to your live e-commerce website!

Comment: If you know some Magento websites that have a store locator or a Google map, you can try to visit them and check the control zoom and if it still there.

Comment: ok the solution is to have <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places,geometry&sensor=false"></script> instead of <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en&libraries=places">

Answer (score 2):

I tried to upload 1.7.2 to one of my Magento projects manually, but got errors in Chrome for mobile on checkout. Also it seems that 1.7.2 differs from 1.7 greatly. Magento is moving to jQuery now, they include jQuery in their Enterprise version, they use it on 1.9. So I think that all new functionality will be written mostly on jQuery and may be some time they will fully remove Prototype as a library with pure support.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tested from chrome on a mobile on my website Magento 1.9.0.1 with prototype 1.7.2 and it seems to work the checkout

Comment: Magento 2 will be jQuery only but is still in alpha development.  As you say, it may be some time.

Comment: it's good to see them moving to jQuery, but again it's a few years too late.  We'll be doing angular in Magento 3.0 :)